# force:createRecord - setting default values dynamically

Tags: lightning-aura-components, create-records

I have a requirement where I need to set the `defaultFieldValues` dynamically (both field name & value). How can I achieve that?

```
var createRecordEvent = $A.get('e.force:createRecord');
if ( createRecordEvent ) {
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        'entityApiName': 'Account',
        'defaultFieldValues': {
            'Name' : 'John',
            'XYZ__C' : '123',
        }
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: u r values what of type of format like collection(sobject)/Map?

Comment: am getting the values from apex as Map<String,String>

Comment: @JayantDas - i tired by passing as createRecordEvent.setParams({ varJSON})  varJSON =dynamical values from apex.

Comment: can you post the structure after use this `JSON.stringify(your value of Map<String,String)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare accounts as object. You can replace **accounts** values from your mapped object.

```
var accounts={ Name: 'John', XYZ__C : '123'};
var createRecordEvent = $A.get('e.force:createRecord');
if ( createRecordEvent ) {
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        'entityApiName': 'Account',
        'defaultFieldValues': accounts
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}
```

Comment: yea i followed the same ,its worked.thank you all.